# Force elpy to work only with .py extension files

Tags: hooks, elpy

Elpy works in every buffer automaticly, however I wan it to work only with python files. The related section of my init.el is:

```
(require 'elpy)
(elpy-use-ipython)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . elpy-mode))
```

I clarify my question: Elpy as a minor mode is activated in all of my buffers, and shadows important key-bindings such as C-c C-c for magit.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "work".  E.g. tell us precisely what behavior you see in non-python buffers and which you dislike there.

Comment: @Stefan I updated my question.

Comment: We're closing this question because it is about an idiosyncratic detail of the OP's init file which is unlikely to be applicable to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I added elpy-mode as hook for flyspell-prog-mode before I enabled elpy, so it activated it globally. I wrote that part of my config one week after I started using Emacs half year ago, So it was easy to forget.

Comment: You can delete your post by the way.

Comment: Since this Q&A post seems to apply to a very specific quirk of your init file, are you okay with deleting the post?  As an alternative, please accept your own answer so we can mark it as completed.